# Effect of changing email template on time based workflow

Tags: time-dependent-workflow

Here's my scenario: A time-based "email alert" workflow action fires that adds an email to the queue. The email is scheduled to be sent 7 days from now. In between now and the time the email is sent, I change the email template associated with the time dependent email alert. My questions:

1. When I change the email template, do any of my queued emails get deleted from the queue? My testing says no, but I'd like to confirm.
2. When the email is actually sent, will it use the original email template or the new email template?

Thank you!

Comment: How about if I change the email field after the email already in queue, the old email or new email address will be sent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When I change the email template, do any of my queued emails get deleted from the queue? My testing says no, but I'd like to confirm.

No. Deleting or deactivating the workflow rule would have an effect, but editing a template would not.

> When the email is actually sent, will it use the original email template or the new email template?

The template is evaluated when the delayed event triggers. In other words, the new email template content would be sent.

Comment: Could I ask you to clarify one thing? When I said "I change the email template" I meant that in the Email Alert settings I actually replace the old template (ID a000000123abC4dAAT)  with an entirely new email template (ID a000000987zyTspAAM). Does your answer to the second question still apply?

Comment: Yes. The system performs the evaluation of what actions to take only when the processor actually executes the time trigger. If this were not true (e.g. if the template was merged ahead of time, then stored for delivery), it could show outdated information or even send the email to the wrong address. The processor basically replicates the workflow execution step during a real record DML event.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. When I change the email template, do any of my queued emails get deleted from the queue? My testing says no, but I'd like to confirm.

No, It will not delete any of your emails. but it only change tour email template.

> 2. When the email is actually sent, will it use the original email template or the new email template?

Yes, it will take new (updated) email template.Because when email fire at that time whatever changes done in the email template it will accept it. so instead of taking old one it will use new one.